# How to create a simple alarm application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an alarm application in iPhone. When the user selects a particular time from datetime picker and sound for alarm and click on the save button, then the alarm sound should play in the background at that particular time and at the same time a page should be displayed which should should contain a snooze button and close button.

When the close button is clicked the alarm is close/completed and when the snooze button is clicked the alarm is postponed to 5 mins. This is app is similar to the inbuilt iPhone alarm app.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html It'll help you with most of what you want to do

Comment: But when my alarm rings how to display my page which contains the snooze and stop buttons in it

Comment: @Evgeniy Shurakov why can't i display a custom page when my alarm rings. is there any other method without using local notificaion

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the current time every second with that of the one set in the uidatepickerview. You can use NSTimer to achieve this.